# Java weird operator ()-> meaning and String operations

Tags: java, string, operators

Today I met part of weird code which I do not understand.

What can mean something like this ()->
for example

```
method( ()-> System.out.println("Hello") );
```

another question is, what is an output of String:

```
[AB][CD]*EF+(X/Y)
```

of course there were not any instance of A, B etc.But I there were answers like

ABCDEFX,
ACEFXX,
ACEFXA,

I do not remember them

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The first is a lambda (new in Java 8); as to the second, well, it is the output string of some class' `.toString()` method...

Comment: That's the syntax of [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: 1. so what mean empty brackets, 2. there were answers which I add to question now.

Comment: empty parentheses mean that the lambda has no arguments

Comment: Can you post the exact wording for question #2? you may be leaving out some important details.

Comment: You have two unrelated questions. One about lambda and one about regexp. It would be better if you separated it in two questions (make a new question about the regexp).

Comment: One more thing. Are you sure about that `/` in your expression? If it's required it should be escaped (or do you mean `[AB][CD]*EF+(X|Y)`?)

Comment: unfortunately I can not write this question perfectly because I saw that in job interview ;/ I wrote what I remember

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose you have an interface that declares one method:

```
public static interface MyFunctionalInterface {
    void m1();
}
```

And you have a method that receives an object of that type as a parameter:

```
public void method(MyFunctionalInterface i) { ... }
```

You can implement that interface and use it immediately using anonymous inner classes like this:

```
method( new MyFunctionalInterface() {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
});
```

In Java 8 you can replace that with a lambda expression such as the one you showed:

```
method( () -> System.out.println("Hello"); );
```

The empty parameters represent the `m1()` method, with no parameters.

Suppose the functional interface you were using had a method with one parameter (if your method had the form `method2(ActionListener s) { ... }` for example), then you would use:

```
method2( e -> System.out.println("Hello"); );
```

which would be the same as doing this:

```
method2( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
});
```

There are many tutorials about Lambda expressions in Java 8. [This one](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) is a good quick-start.